# Why can't I get the login page to show up?

Tags: php, authentication

I have been working on this code for a while, but I am having an issue because the PHP I have before my HTML code for this login page is not working. Can someone look at this and tell me why logging in PHP code is tripping over itself? This code is above the Html code for the website paged "login.php".

```
<?php
session_start();

// Set the session cookie lifetime to 0
session_set_cookie_params(0);

$accounts = array(
    'admin' => 'admin',
    'publisher' => 'publisher',
    'customer' => 'customer'
);

// Check if the user has submitted the login form
if (isset($_POST['username']) && isset($_POST['password'])) {
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];

    // Check if the username and password match an account
    if (isset($accounts[$username]) && $accounts[$username] == $password) {
        // Set the access level in the session
        $_SESSION['access_level'] = $username;

        // Redirect to the appropriate page
        if ($username == 'admin') {
            header('Location: EmployeeArray.php');
            exit;
        } else if ($username == 'publisher') {
            header('Location: EmployeeArray.php');
            exit;
        } else if ($username == 'customer') {
            header('Location: Products.php');
            exit;
        }
    } else {
        $error = 'Invalid username or password.';
    }
}

// Check if the session is already set, and redirect to the login page if it is not
if (!isset($_SESSION['access_level'])) {
    header('Location: login.php');
    exit();
}


// Check if the user is logged in
if (isset($_SESSION['access_level'])) {
    // User is logged in, show appropriate content
    if ($_SESSION['access_level'] == 'admin') {
        echo 'Welcome, admin! <a href="LogoutQuestion.php">Log out</a>';
    } else if ($_SESSION['access_level'] == 'publisher') {
        echo 'Welcome, publisher! <a href="LogoutQuestion.php">Log out</a>';
    } else if ($_SESSION['access_level'] == 'customer') {
        echo 'Welcome, customer! <a href="LogoutQuestion.php">Log out</a>';
    }
} else {
    // User is not logged in, show login form
?>
```

Comment: When `$_SESSION['access_level']` is not set you have an infinite redirect.

Comment: So how do I fix that? What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the script above is part of `login.php` then calling the `header` function when testing `!isset($_SESSION['access_level'])` would be the cause of the infinite redirect. You could simply remove that logic test.

However the confusing part is why you allow users to return to the `login` page when they are logged in - the portion of code that begins `if (isset($_SESSION['access_level'])) {` displays the logout link but if the login is successful they should be redirected to another page ( Products.php or EmployeeArray.php ) and will not see this `logout` link. To remedy that the below code sets this HTML logout link in a session variable when the user successfully completes the login - that session variable can then be used on the page to which they are redirected.

I tested the following and it all seemed to work but I might have missed the point somewhere.

```
<?php

    #login.php

    error_reporting( E_ALL );
    
    # call this **before** you start the session!
    session_set_cookie_params(0);
    session_start();
    
    # If the user is logged in, redirect to the appropriate location
    if( isset( $_SESSION['access_level'], $_SESSION['redirect'] ) ) {
        exit( header( sprintf('Location: %s', $_SESSION['redirect'] ) ) );
    }
    
    # process the POST request
    if( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST' && isset(
        $_POST['username'],
        $_POST['password']
    )){
        $accounts = array(
            'admin'         => 'admin',
            'publisher'     => 'publisher',
            'customer'      => 'customer'
        );
        
        $username = $_POST['username'];
        $password = $_POST['password'];

        # Supplied username/password is in accordance with the $accounts array
        if( isset( $accounts[ $username ] ) && $accounts[ $username ] == $password ) {
            
            switch( $accounts[ $username ] ){
                case 'admin':       $location='EmployeeArray.php';  break;
                case 'publisher':   $location='EmployeeArray.php';  break;
                case 'customer':    $location='Products.php';       break;
            }
            # set some useful session variables
            $_SESSION['access_level']=$accounts[ $username ];
            $_SESSION['html_logout']=sprintf('Welcome, %s! <a href="LogoutQuestion.php">Log out</a>', $_SESSION['access_level'] );
            $_SESSION['redirect']=$location;
            
            exit( header( sprintf('Location: %s', $location ) ) );
        } else {
            $_SESSION['error'] = 'Invalid username or password.';
        }
    }
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='en'>
    <head>
        <meta charset='utf-8' />
        <title>login</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php
            if( !empty( $_SESSION['error'] ) ){
                printf('<h1>%s</h1>', $_SESSION['error'] );
                unset( $_SESSION['error'] );
            }
        ?>
        <form method='post'>
            <label>Username<input type='text' name='username' /></label>
            <label>Password<input type='password' name='password' /></label>
            <input type='submit' />
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

And the various other scripts:

```
<?php
    session_start();
    
    $script='EmployeeArray.php';
    printf(
        '<h1>%s - %s</h1>
        <p>%s</p>',
        $script,
        $_SESSION['access_level'],
        $_SESSION['html_logout']
    );
?>

<?php
    session_start();
    
    $script='Products.php';
    printf(
        '<h1>%s - %s</h1>
        <p>%s</p>',
        $script,
        $_SESSION['access_level'],
        $_SESSION['html_logout']
    );
?>

<?php

    #LogoutQuestion.php
    
    session_start();
    $_SESSION = array();
    if( ini_get("session.use_cookies") ) {
        $params = session_get_cookie_params();
        setcookie(session_name(), '', time() - 42000,
            $params["path"], 
            $params["domain"],
            $params["secure"],
            $params["httponly"]
        );
    }
    session_destroy();
    exit( header('Location: login.php') );
?>
```